# React Native Android: Is renderToHardwareTextureAndroid working?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I am having performance and "jank" issues while scrolling on a Android React Native app. The JS FPS drops from ~60fps down to ~3-10fps while scrolling.

The content being scrolled DOES include images containing transparency and text layered over images. If I remove the images, performance increases significantly.

The above scenario sounds like a perfect case for [`renderToHardwareTextureAndroid`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance#moving-a-view-on-the-screen-scrolling-translating-rotating-drops-ui-thread-fps). That said, enabling this property on a `View` containing the images/text seems to have no effect at all.

**How can I confirm this feature is truly turned on and working as expected? Is it possible that something I am doing/not doing is forcing the hardware rendering to not take place?**

Comment: Size of the images seemed have impacted my app drastically in my case when having them scrolled. Are you sure your images aren't too big?

Comment: @iuliu.net are you referring to the filesize, resolution, or displayed "size" of the images?

Comment: Displayed size is a non factor, but the others (filesize / resolution) usually have been performance issue sources for my apps

Comment: did you get any solution for this? I also want to add this in my project

Comment: @Shubham my issues went away when I switched all images to this: https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image